# Magento - SQL query programmatically

Tags: mysql, magento

I have a SQL query that i would like to write with Magento's collection methods but i don't know how to.
I know that i have to use the getSelect() and joinLeft() methods, but don't know how to put a select inside a left join.

The query is :

```
SELECT
    p.photo_id,
    p.photo_name,
    s.step_id,
    s.step_name
FROM Photo p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        photo_id, MAX(step_id) AS max_step_id
    FROM photoStep
    GROUP BY photo_id
) ps
    ON ps.photo_id = p.photo_id
LEFT JOIN Steps s
    ON s.step_id = ps.max_step_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your best option here would be to try to avoid using the subquery. So I would start by reworking the SQL query and then use the functions groupByField & addExpressionFieldToSelect.

```
->groupByField('photo_id')
->addExpressionFieldToSelect("max_step_id", 'MAX({{step_id}})', 'step_id')
```